# Output days of each month and mark weekends in color

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I try to display the individual days of a month and to color the weekend. The current month (May 2022) works without any problems, see picture. However, the other months are marked in the wrong color. However, the dates are correct for every month! Only the switch case somehow doesn't work properly.

```
function Items({ eintrag, loescheEintrag, tage }) {
const array = [];
const d = new Date();
console.log(tage); // tage Array fine here, see pic
{
tage?.map((tag, tagIndex) => {
  const newDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), tagIndex + 1);
  const day = getDayName(newDate, "de-DE");

  switch (newDate.getDay()) {
    case 0:
      //if Sunday
      array.push(<ListItem> {`${day} - ${tag} `} </ListItem>)
      break;
    case 6:
      //if Saturday
      array.push(<ListItem> {`${day} - ${tag} `} </ListItem>)
    break;
    default:
      array.push(<ListItem> {`${day} - ${tag} `} </ListItem>)

}
```

Mai 2022

[image]

output is correct!

[image]

Juni 2022

[image]

output is incorrect. 06/01 is a Wednesday and should not be marked in color

[image]

Comment: ```const d = new Date();``` is defined above with current date (May 2022). Which is always calculates the newDate by May ```d.getMonth()```

Answer (score 0):

I had to configure the "tag" I get in the map with Moment.js.

switch (Wait(day, "DD-MM-YYYY").format("dddd")) { }